# Can't get row number correct using partition over

Tags: sql, window-functions

I'm trying to get this query to output a certain way. Basically this is the output I'm getting:

```
+-------+------------+-------------+----------+--------+
| Col_A |    Date    |  Subscr_Id  | Segment  | RowNum |
+-------+------------+-------------+----------+--------+
|     1 | 16/09/2008 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |      1 |
|     2 | 17/09/2008 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |      2 |
|     3 | 24/09/2008 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |      3 |
|     4 | 25/09/2008 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |      4 |
|     5 | 24/06/2009 | 5,954,766   | CONSUMER |      1 |
|     6 | 01/09/2009 | 5,954,766   | CONSUMER |      2 |
|     7 | 09/11/2009 | 5,954,766   | CONSUMER |      3 |
|     8 | 31/12/2009 | 5,954,766   | CONSUMER |      4 |
|     9 | 01/01/2010 | 5,954,766   | CONSUMER |      5 |
|    10 | 31/01/2010 | 5,954,766   | CONSUMER |      6 |
|    11 | 28/02/2010 | 5,954,766   | CONSUMER |      7 |
|    12 | 01/04/2010 | 5,954,766   | CONSUMER |      8 |
|    13 | 28/06/2010 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |      5 |
|    14 | 14/11/2010 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |      6 |
|    15 | 09/06/2011 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |      7 |
|    16 | 22/09/2011 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |      8 |
|    17 | 18/12/2012 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |      9 |
|    18 | 12/02/2017 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |     10 |
|    19 | 14/02/2017 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |     11 |
|    20 | 20/02/2017 | 5,954,766   | UNKNOWN  |     12 |
|    21 | 16/09/2008 | 208,333,201 | ?        |      1 |
|    22 | 18/12/2012 | 208,333,201 | ?        |      2 |
|    23 | 12/02/2017 | 208,333,201 | CONSUMER |      1 |
|    24 | 13/02/2017 | 208,333,201 | CONSUMER |      2 |
|    25 | 14/02/2017 | 208,333,201 | CONSUMER |      3 |
|    26 | 15/02/2017 | 208,333,201 | CONSUMER |      4 |
|    27 | 20/02/2017 | 208,333,201 | CONSUMER |      5 |
|    28 | 28/02/2017 | 208,333,201 | CONSUMER |      6 |
+-------+------------+-------------+----------+--------+
```

I basically want the `RowNum` column to reset to 1 whenever the `Subscr_Id` or `Segment` value changes.  It almost works, but as you can see on the thirteenth row, the `RowNum` starts back at 5 rather than resetting to one.

The query I'm using is as follows:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Subscr_Id, Segment ORDER BY st.Subscr_Id, st.Effective_From_Dt) AS RowNum
```

Is anyone able to give me any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify adjacent values, even when they are separated by other values.  One method for doing this is to identify the adjacent rows using the difference of row numbers, and then using `row_number()` after that:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by subscr_id, seqnum - seqnum_s
                          order by col_a
                         ) as rownum
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by subscr_id order by col_a) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by subscr_id, segment order by col_a) as seqnum_s,
      from t
     ) t;
```

The logic is a bit tricky.  Run the subquery to to see what the seqnum values are.  You'll see how the difference identifies the groups that you want.